# make append happen only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have on a list a button that fire this event:

**js:**

```
$(this).parents('tr')
       .find('.class')
       .append("<input type='text' size='5'/>");
```

its possible to make this append happen just in the first time?

like a `return false`, dont know.

Thanks!

Comment: I saw this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115951/jquery-run-only-once  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that this behavior is happening on a `click` event, you can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/).  E.g.,

```
$('#my-button').one('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr')
       .find('.class')
       .append("<input type='text' size='5'/>");
});
```

---

Edit: using `delegate`:

```
var selector = '#my-button',
    handler = function(e) {
        // prevent default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        // make sure this only runs once
        $(document).undelegate(selector, 'click', handler);
        // actual behavior
        $(this).parents('tr')
           .find('.class')
           .append("<input type='text' size='5'/>");
    };
$(document).delegate(selector, 'click', handler);
```

Comment: will try this, brb with the result.

Comment: Updated. `delegate` is more efficient than `live`, so hopefully that's OK. If you really need `live`, I'll update again :)

Comment: i was thinking to use the delagete , now u tell me , will use! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead of click().